# Appcelerator Titanium UI textfield with image

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I am a beginner in titanium development. I need help to design an app with a textfield contains image icon like below image. i am not using app designer. Please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEYch.png)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

create a common input controller

common/input.xml

```
<View id="container">
    <ImageView id="icon"/>
    <TextField id="input">
</View>
```

common/input.tss

```
"#container":{
    height: 50,
    top: 10,
    left: 15,
    right: 15,
    borderColor: 'blue'
}

"#icon":{
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    left: 10
}

"#input":{
    left: 50,
    right: 10
    //Add your default TextField input here
}
```

common/input.js

```
//set controller Style
if ($.args.icon) {
    $.icon.image = $.args.icon;
} else {
    $.icon.visible = false;
    $.input.left = 10;
}

//custom textField style send in inputStyle
if ($.args.inputStyle) {
    _.extend($.input, $.args.inputStyle);
}

$.getValue = function() {
    return $.input.value;
};
$.setValue = function(value) {
    $.input.value = value;
};
```

Now you can use directly this input style where you want, for exemple on your login screen

login.xml

```
<Window>
  ..
    <Require id="email" src="common/input" type="view" />
    <Require id="password" src="common/input" type="view" />
  ..
</Window>
```

login.tss

```
"#email":{
    icon: '/images/email.png',
    inputStyle: {
        hintText: 'Email Adress'
    }
}
"#password":{
    icon: '/images/password.png',
    inputStyle: {
        hintText: 'Password',
        passwordMask: true
    }
}
```

and finally you can get the value like this

login.js

```
var emailValue = $.email.getValue();
var passwordValue = $.password.getValue();
```